# Calling a function in a before delete trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

id like to call this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE orders_salary_manage2 AS
  FUNCTION total_calc(p_order in NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY orders_salary_manage2 AS
  tot_orders NUMBER;

FUNCTION total_calc(p_order in NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
   c_price product.unit_price%type;
   c_prod_desc product.product_desc%type;
   v_total_cost NUMBER := 0;
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT product_desc, unit_price 
      FROM product 
      WHERE product_id IN (SELECT fk2_product_id 
                           FROM order_line 
                            WHERE fk1_order_id = p_order);
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 into c_prod_desc, c_price;
      v_total_cost := v_total_cost + c_price;
      EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   return v_total_cost;
END;
```

from this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_order_total
BEFORE DELETE ON placed_order 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_old_order NUMBER := :old.order_id;
BEGIN
total_calc(v_old_order);
END;
```

but i keep getting this error, note there is no error number just this:

Error at line 4: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

1. BEFORE DELETE ON placed_order
2. FOR EACH ROW
3. DECLARE
4. v_old_order NUMBER := :old.order_id;
5. BEGIN

im new to pl/sql and just not sure what is causing the problem. When a user deletes an order from the orders table the trigger should call the function to add up all the products on the order.

Thank you

Comment: The trigger code that you've shown doesn't call the `add_order_func` function at all.  Do you mean you're getting that error from the current trigger code as shown, or you get that error when you try to change it to call the function?  If the former, then perhaps the problem is with the `total_calc` procedure that you are calling.  If the latter, then show the trigger code that is actually trying to call the function.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, sorry i showed the wrong function, i'v been working for hours now and my brains switching off. I'm basically trying to make the function execute when a delete occurs and the parameter passed to the function should be the order_id (PK) of the row

Comment: we miss the actual error description (ORA-XXXXX: bla bla bla..)

Answer (score 1):

(Considering your Package compiled with no errors) Use-

```
ret_val:= orders_salary_manage2.total_calc(v_old_order);
```

The `ret_val` must be a `NUMBER` since the package function `total_calc` returns a `NUMBER`. A function MUST always return its outcoume to a variable (like `ret_val`) depending on the type of the return value the data type of the variable must be declared.

The syntax to call Pacakaged Procedures and functions is -

```
<RETURN_VARIABLE> := PACKAGE_NAME.<FUNCTION_NAME>();
PACKAGE_NAME.<PROCEDURE_NAME>(); --Since Procedure never returns
```

Also note that if your package is in a different SCHEMA and has no PUBLIC SYNONYM then you will have to prefix the schema name like `<SCHEMA>.PACKAGE_NAME.<FUNCTION_NAME>()` (considering the calling schema has execute permissions on the package).

So,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_order_total
BEFORE DELETE ON placed_order 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_old_order NUMBER := :old.order_id;
   v_ret_val   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   v_ret_val := orders_salary_manage2.total_calc(v_old_order);
   --...Do stuff with v_ret_val
END;
```

Comment: Hi annjawn I managed to figure it out last night and came up with this: 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_order_total
BEFORE DELETE ON placed_order 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_old_order NUMBER := :old.order_id;
v_total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_total := total_calc(v_old_order);
   DELETE FROM order_line WHERE fk1_order_id = v_old_order ;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_total);
END;

Thank you for your reply though! Your right I needed to store the result of the func in a variable!